# How to create a 4D matrix from a vector of matrices in OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

Suppose that I collect same size, depth and channel images/matrices into a `vector`. So, these images are `r*c*d` each and I have `m` of them in my vector as follows.

```
vector<string> imgs; --> there are m image paths in these, all are r*c*d resolution
vector<Mat> vec;
for (auto img: imgs ){
    vec.push_back(cv::imread(img, COLOR_BGR)); //or gray. doesn't really matter
}
```

Now, I want to create a 4D Matrix. For example, in python `np.array(vec)` would have given me that (assuming `vec` is a list). I would like to the same in OpenCV c++ but I couldn't find a solution for this.

I don't want to create a 4D matrix with `Mat m(dims, size, type);`, then iterate through all pixels and copy the value as it is very inefficient. I would like to have a technique that will just consider `vec<Mat>` as `4D Mat` so that it is going to be super fast. Note that I can have `100` full-resolution images.

I am using Opencv4.2 and c++ on Mac.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours today, I coincidentally found an answer to my question. I will leave the answer here to have a reference for those who battle with OpenCV's documentation to find the correct answer.

```
vector<int> dims = {m, r, c}; //dimensions
cv::Mat m (3, &dims[0], imgs[0].type(), &imgs[0]);
```

This creates the 4D matrix from `imgs` vector where the type is one of `CV_8UC1`, `CV_8UC3` or `CV_8UC4` depending on the number of channels. The good thing is it doesn't copy the vector.

Although this is not part of the question, to access a pixel in the 4D matrix, you can do the following:

```
int x = v1, i = v2, j = v3, c = v4; //v1-4 are some random values within their ranges
cout << (int)m.at<Mat>(x).at<Vec3b>(i,j)[c] << " " 
     << (int)imgs[x].at<Vec3b> (i,j)[c] << endl;
```

Both will print `c`-th channel of `i,j`-th index of `x`-th image.